# Can't restore dconf user file

Tags: backup, deja-dup, dconf, duplicity

This is on Ubuntu 15.10. I had a *~/.config/dconf/user*  file of about 19kb. I back this up whenever I do a Deja-dup backup. After I recently reinstalled Ubuntu the newly installed *~/.config/dconf/user* file is about 10 kb. When I delete the new file and restore the original with duplicity it shows up in Nautilus as 19 kb as expected. However when I reboot the system, the file has somehow reverted to the size of 10 kb.
Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the user file you want in ~/.config/dconf/ named as user.old

Then go ctrl+alt+f3 to go to a tty. When there login & from prompt -

`rm /home/yourusername/.config/dconf/user`

`mv /home/yourusername/.config/dconf/user.old /home/yourusername/.config/dconf/user`

`sudo reboot`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that with the same result. When I reboot the old file is back.

Comment: I take that back. If i follow those instructions exactly it works. So why did that work and a duplicity restore not work?

Comment: Basically /dconf /user is loaded into memory on log in & when you log out or restart it's rewritten from mem. So to replace that file you need to do it outside of your 'normal' user env. like from a tty or from another install or other user session. This is also why you need to restart from the tty after replacing, if you went back ala ctrl+alt+f7 you'd end up with the orig. user file in mem when logging out or restarting.

Comment: That explains things. I'm thinking that I might be better off  using `dconf dump` to dump the settings to a text file. Then  use `dconf load` when I want to restore the settings to the database. I would need to do the dump periodically (in a cron job?) to keep the text file up to date. This technique is explained here  (in the checked answer) : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199836/how-can-i-view-the-content-of-a-backup-of-the-dconf-database-file